# How can I add code to the head element when posting a code snippet?

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I wanted to post a code snippet with a `meta` tag in the document head, so I created a code snippet with a complete HTML document.

Later I saw that Stack Overflow automatically creates an HTML document and my code was put inside that.

Here is an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    </head>
    <body>
        Test!
    </body>
</html>
```

If you run the code and look inside the source code of the iframe you can see it's rubbish. There are two HTML documents now.

So how can I do it properly?

Comment: Use a blank iframe and write all the content including scripts into the iframe.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929613/where-do-i-put-viewport-meta-tag-in-jsfiddle

Answer (score 34):

If dynamically creating the `<meta>` tag isn't enough, there's a way to put the tag in *directly*, without JavaScript, through a hack. The text in the CodeMirror textareas will be inserted *verbatim* into the base HTML markup. For example:

```js
// JavaScript code goes here
```

```css
/* CSS goes here */
```

```html
<!-- HTML goes here -->

Right click and Inspect me
```

Results in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        /* CSS goes here */
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <!-- HTML goes here -->

Right click and Inspect me
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // JavaScript code goes here
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, if you put `</style>` in the CSS section, you'll be in the `<head>` proper, and you can change it to your heart's content (make sure to start up the `<style>` again right before the end so that the HTML is valid.) For example:

```css
</style>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<style>
```

results in

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        </style>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<style>
    </style>
    </head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is hideous. People, don't use this. Just write a normal code block instead of a snippet. The extra 10 seconds required for the reader to save your code into a file and then open it in a browser is less than it'll take for them to understand this hack. We got on fine without snippets for years before they got added; a front-end web question not having a snippet is seriously not going to kill anyone.

Answer (score 9):

You can add that Meta tag via JavaScript but I'm not sure if that will help for whatever you're trying to fix or demonstrate.

```js
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.setAttribute('name',"viewport");
meta.setAttribute('content',"width=device-width");
head.appendChild(meta);
```

```html
Test!
```

Here is what you get in the Developer Console of Chrome when you run the snippet:

[image: html in inspector]