# Please Fix Stack Snippets

Tags: bug, status-review, stack-snippets

Please fix the many outstanding issues with Stack Snippets:

- [Why won't this snippet with async await work here on Stack Overflow snippet editor?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386097/why-wont-this-snippet-with-async-await-work-here-on-stack-overflow-snippet-edit)
- [Update the version of Babel Standalone (and others) used by Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386096/update-the-version-of-babel-standalone-and-others-used-by-stack-snippets)
- [Snippets aren't working when refreshing an edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388534/snippets-arent-working-when-refreshing-an-edit)
- [Occasional failure to save when improving a question using the Snippet Editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372944/occasional-failure-to-save-when-improving-a-question-using-the-snippet-editor)
- [Stack Snippets logging nested objects weirdly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361306/stack-snippets-logging-nested-objects-weirdly)
- [How can I add code to the head element when posting a code snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382545/1264804)
- ...

In some cases the fix is literally as easy as grabbing canon's latest version. In other cases, updating the list in a select box (literally, just changing some option values). Others may involve a little bit of actual work.

I just ran into that first one again. It's *asinine* that Babel is so old in Stack Snippets that it doesn't support features most browsers now support natively.

Comment: They have more important to do: [New post formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353446/386331) ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif - It was only masterful self-control that prevented my mentioning that in the post above. :-D

Comment: I wonder if it would be better to just integrate with codepen or something rather than maintaining functionality which arguably is outside of SO's core scope.

Comment: @ivarni - That'd be fine by me too, but would probably be more work than fixing the list above. Stack Snippets are really simple and mostly work well enough (aside, obviously, from the things above :-) ). An integration sounds like a lot of up-front work and then ongoing maintenance as things change on one side or the other... :-)

Comment: And then there are the holy wars -- "Y u no use stackblitz!? so much betr thn codepin!" And the legal/license stuff...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yeah, I did not consider the whole licensing thing. It might not be compatible. Also it would go against the idea that content should be hosted somewhere (here) it's guaranteed to be preserved.

Comment: What?? Make it easier to provide code solutions when their resources could be doing important stuff like unintelligible emoji *thanks* widgets?

Comment: Another *"6-8 weeks"* slides by

Comment: But [tracking pixels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411662/outdated-answers-we-re-adding-an-answer-view-tracking-pixel?cb=1), now, there's something that's actually important. Not like the primary tool used in the biggest tags on SO, which is clearly unimportant.

Comment: Wait, so it took them like 1 year to basically do some css, but they won't discuss a feature that really helps users create good questions?