# Outdated Answers: We’re adding an answer view tracking pixel

Tags: discussion, answers, announcement

As part of the [Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project), we are introducing a new, permanent answer view tracking pixel that records when specific answers are viewed. It will be rolled out later this week in stages, starting with 1% of our traffic and working our way up to 100%.

We currently don't track if and when specific answers are viewed, and this is hampering our ability to do data analysis for a new sorting algorithm that will weight more recent upvotes more heavily than older ones. The answer view pixel will collect metadata about the answer, such as position on page, score, etc.

Our definition of when an answer is viewed is broad and we're purposefully triggering when the answer is first visible, not when it's been meaningfully read. It will be triggered when you've only partially read an answer or you scroll past it quickly. This came up in our planning and we decided not to exclude these additional views in our collection. We're taking this into account when we do our analysis, will filter out the noise, and won't let it skew our findings.

For the time being, we are only recording requests to the answer view pixel data in our traffic logs and are not recording the view counts in our primary production databases. This means that there are no immediate plans to display this data on the site, make it available in SEDE, or expose it via the API.

The answer pixel is classified in the same category as a performance cookie, so if you have opted out of performance cookies in your cookie settings, then per our [cookie policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy), we will not collect this data from you. The performance category doesn't include any targeting or advertising-related cookies, only things that help us understand how people are using our site.

Comment: I'm interested by how this works with very long answers?

Comment: I'm curious if my adblocker is blocking this, as this is something I'd actually want to support. Is it possible to get some information about the pixel?

Comment: Would this system be confused by browsers preloading images outside of the viewport? Or if the pixels are only added by Javascript when in view, why not just send the data directly, perhaps through the websocket?

Comment: Tracking pixels sound like such an old technology. Why not use [Intersection Observers](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)? They’re supported in all your [supported browsers](//browsers.stackoverflow.design/).

Comment: You hear "old technology", I hear "well supported".

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier That would be a good counter-argument, except for the fact that Sebastian mentioned IO is supported in all the browsers SO already supports anyway.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier we count an answer as viewed when you've seen the post's score in the voting controls - it's a little broad, but we're aiming to over-collect here rather than under-collect

Comment: @Cerbrus If you're looking to block this with your adblocker, the tracking pixel route has the form `/answers/{postId}/ivc/{hash}`

Comment: @KylePollard So this'll be a lazy-loading implementation where you don't show call the resource until the scroll position is met, one time for each answer on the page? Or will there be one tracking pixel and a counter that increments once for each answer whose score you roll across

Comment: @KylePollard: I'm looking to make sure I'm _not_ blocking it, but thanks :D

Comment: @JohnDvorak We're using [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) in our implementation, so there's no worries here on triggering views outside of the viewport

Comment: @SebastianSimon that's exactly our implementation, and the discussion around browser support is what lead to our browser support page now having a nice caniuse.com search box at the top

Comment: @TylerH We count individual views for each answer, but only once per answer. If you reload the page, you'll be eligible to view each answer again

Comment: It seems to me that you really count scrolling. How much do users scroll on a page. You can't see if they read the post or not. I have a script that will scroll to the accepted Answer. I wonder if you will count all the ones I scroll past.

Comment: @Scratte We will be over-collecting when users scroll. This will happen when someone scrolls down to answer since the answer text box is after all of the answers. This came up in our planning and we decided not to exclude these in our collection. We're taking this into account when we do our analysis and won't let it skew our findings.

Comment: @KylePollard maybe debounce the collection to only fire if the scroll position stays fixed for several seconds? It's not like the reading speed is infinitely fast :)

Comment: @OlegValter It's something we'll reconsider if we iterate again in the future. :) We don't want to exclude anything for our initial analysis.

Comment: What we really need is eye implants on everyone.

Comment: @KylePollard this is probably something about the user agent, but if I link a specific answer, would it count any answer that came into the viewport?

Comment: @Braiam Agreed that it depends on the user agent, but in my testing the answers above the one you linked to don't trigger. Our answer tracking doesn't start until the [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) event, and by then your browser should have already scrolled you to the specific answer. I haven't dug into it, but I expect that a function like [`scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo) would not trigger events for the answers it scrolls past completely.

Comment: @matt `[status-planned]` 

Comment: @KylePollard methinks `scrollTo` still triggers native events, though...

Comment: @OlegValter Oh yeah, I expect it will still get triggered if you're adding `behavior: 'smooth'` to it, just not in the standard case where it immediately changes the position. I think `IntersectionObserver` is only checking when the page is visibly rendered, and if the intermediate posts aren't ever rendered because they scroll position immediately jumped, then I don't think they'll be triggered.

Comment: @KylePollard hmmm, that's a good idea,  true :) On thing that worries me a little, though, is that I definitely noticed smooth scroll on pages when developing userscripts - it is especially apparent on pages with extreme amount of answers (like the review queue updates) - I need to check to make sure, though, my memory might be playing tricks on  me.

Comment: **My privacy!** Can I opt out?

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE the last paragraph of the post has instructions on how to opt out. You'll want to go to your cookie settings and opt out of performance cookies.

Comment: Given the whole Intersection Observer thing, is there actually a tracking pixel here, or did you just use that term in the title because people are more familiar with those?

Comment: @KylePollard As anything privacy related, that should be an opt-in, not an opt-out. I'm kinda getting sick of having to jump through hoops to disable that sort of stuff on every website I visit.

Comment: @DanMašek if you opted out of the performance metrics cookies, you also opted out of this.

Comment: @DanMašek What you're asking for is exactly how our cookie consent already works - performance cookies aren't enabled by default and are opt-in. You can still opt-out after. Our [original announcement of these controls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359358/we-re-adding-more-user-controls-for-cookie-consent) and our [cookie policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy) have more details

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica It's more for familiarity - if we were going by the strictest of definitions, then it's probably considered a [web beacon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_beacon) which is a superset of tracking pixels, but I don't think that web beacon is a commonly understood term. (At least, not more understood than tracking pixels are)

Comment: Does this mean that the "reached" KPI might mean something? :P

Comment: "..a new sorting algorithm that will weight more recent upvotes more heavily than older ones.." I hope the same will go for downvotes. :)

Comment: @Larnu "Does this mean that the "reached" KPI might mean something?" Then please also track the time and display statistics like: "XX times people scrolled to your answer / over your answer / and stopped for XX seconds / stopped so long that they may have read it".

Comment: Question is probably how many people have turned performance cookies on if they are opt-in. Probably depends on how big the button for the all cookie consent was.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable use of tracking pixels. I'm generally wary of tracking, but I appreciate the straight-forward announcement and explanation of what they are being used for.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder There's a section in the [cookie policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy) with a link to "cookie settings". There's also a link to cookie settings in the footer of the page, under the "company" heading. You can manage your opt-in/opt-out there.

Comment: @KylePollard Besides these tracking pixels, do any other StackExchange URLs include `/ivc/`?  It will be better if these URLs can be isolated without requiring multiple wildcards in the URL.

Comment: That seems . . . really complicated. Are you actually sure you need it? Now the answers will be in some sort-of-order but not really? I don't know if that's an improvement.

Comment: @Neil what are you responding to? this question isn't announcing a change to sort order, just more data collection.

Comment: I've noticed that when I want to add the first comment to a page with at least one answer, when I (click on "add a comment") focus on the textbox, the screen will autoscroll and include the top of the first answer and include its voting buttons.  This means that a very regular action will be skewing the accuracy on the top sorted answer.

Comment: @KevinB this "new sorting algorithm that will weight more recent upvotes more heavily than older ones". I take it to mean that newer votes will be worth more in how the answers are ranked. I imagine that will lead to all sorts of complications. (Though this might be good for ties.)

Comment: @Neil fortunately, that's not a thing yet. I haven't seen SO suggest that as a possibility, only users.

Comment: @Neil we are exploring ideas about offering a trending sort. This data will be used in helping to develop those models. We will post about this separately when plans are more developed.

Comment: @KylePollard if only there were a massive repository of programming knowledge somewhere so people could find out what a web beacon was, instead of misleadingly claiming to be using a tracking pixel.

Comment: Will answer views stay intact when questions are merged? And will this data be available on the SEDE?

Comment: @canon No, these views won't stay intact across merges as they're just in our traffic logs. There are no immediate plans to display this data on the site, make it available in SEDE, or expose it via the API.

Comment: @KylePollard That's disappointing. Thanks for the answer, though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Our over-collection of answer views is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) here, and there's some great points on the [risks involved with it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411698/3023052).

I hear the point that our metric isn't accurately tracking when someone has read the answer. We won't be making the assumption that *"answer pixel triggered"* means *"the answer was meaningfully read and understood"* but rather *"answer pixel triggered"* means *"the top part of the answer was visible on the page at any point"*. This is modelled after our question views which trigger when the page is loaded - not when you've meaningfully understood the answer.

The case where the top of the next answer is visible and triggered early is definitely an overcollection, but it's a tradeoff. It's difficult to assign the tracking to the dynamic content in the post, so our best options were the voting controls or the signature after the answer. We preferred the overcollection of the voting controls over the under-collection of the signature.

We're also being mindful of the number of requests we generate. We have to be careful about passively generating extra requests on the question page when you scroll since it's the busiest page on our site. We could trigger an additional time when you finish reading the answer, but we want to avoid any unnecessary requests.

That being said, I understand the fear of bad data leading to bad decisions and that we should be cautious when using this data. Maybe *"the top part of the answer was visible at any point"* is too noisy? I had a conversation with the data team that will be handling the analysis and discuss the concerns outlined in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411698/3023052), and they offered two ways they'll be reducing the noise here at analysis time rather than collection time:

- We can tell when you've viewed the bottom of an answer when you've triggered an answer view for the next answer. (This will be an *under-collection* of viewing the entire answer since you won't always view the next answer, but will provide a good lower bound of answer views. We're aware that this won't happen for the last answer on the page since there's no subsequent answer there.)
- We can tell when you've rapidly scrolled past answers since the timestamp of each view will be unreasonably close together

In the future there's still room to iterate on this - if we see too much noise or we're unhappy with how this is collecting data, we can still modify the trigger criteria. If we ever want to expose answer views in the future, we may consider making this a more meaningful metric. However, for the purpose of our analysis in the scope of the outdated answers project, this kind of over-collection combined with filtering out the noise is exactly what we're looking for.

To summarize:

- Our definition of a view for the purposes of this collection is when the answer was visible, not when the answer was meaningfully read
- We're going to filter out noisy views
- We have an upper bound for a meaningful answer view by looking at when the top of the answer was visible
- We have a lower bound for a meaningful answer view by looking at when the top of the next answer was visible

We'll be sure to share when and how we're using this answer view data to drive future decisions like we did with [the copy and voting data during the unpinning experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/3023052). I hope that you can continue to keep us honest in our data collection and analysis as we continue work on outdated answers - I sincerely appreciate the feedback and questions.

Comment: I added a paraphrase of your comment to this effect to the question itself, for more visibility. Please do correct/elaborate on it as necessary.

Comment: *"I hear the point that our metric isn't accurately tracking when someone has read the question."* Did you mean *the answer* there at the end?

Comment: *"...so our best options were the voting controls or the signature after the question..."* Why is that best? I probably would have opted for something in the middle or perhaps somewhere in the first half, if I had to pick a single spot (rather than doing something more rigorous).

Comment: Thank you for writing this up, much appreciated! I can't say I'm persuaded. I really don't buy that filtering will make it possible to meaningfully use the data (except for the timestamps part, that makes sense). But I'm just one person.

Comment: Relevant: [*The Law of Truly Large Numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_truly_large_numbers).

Comment: "It's difficult to assign the tracking to the dynamic content in the post, so our best options were the voting controls or the signature after the answer. We preferred the overcollection of the voting controls over the under-collection of the signature." - you could do both. Would that have impacted performance too much?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder re: options, I don't think we have any other static controls on a question between the voting controls and the signature that show for all users, the only other component between them is the user content of the post. (Though, I'm grouping in the history button with the rest of the voting controls)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Adding two passively triggered network requests for each answer was considered too expensive at our scale, so we chose not to do both.

Comment: @KylePollard - Thanks for reaching out. :-) I don't think a tracking pixel is the right tool for this job, regardless of placement. But if you want placement suggestions, I'd say go for left of the post body about 1/3 to 1/2 of a page height from the top of the page body (but not below the midpoint of the answer). (If it can't be that dynamic, perhaps pick an avg page height and post height and use that, again limited to 1/2 the height of the post body via CSS.) But while I think that would be *better*, I don't think it would be *good*. Sorry, not trying to be difficult. :-)

Answer (score 45):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

#### Too much noise to signal

- This will over-report "viewing" of answers that are at the top of the sort order (whatever sort order you use).
- I don't really "view" an answer in any meaningful way when I'm scrolling past it looking for something else. Examples:

  - If I'm looking for an accepted or upvoted answer when not using the by-votes sort order (which I often don't), I'll just be scrolling past a number of rubbish answers.
  - If I'm looking for a newer answer when using the by-votes sort order, I'll be scrolling past old answers.
- The top of an answer (with its voting buttons and score, where [Kyle said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411662/outdated-answers-we-re-adding-an-answer-view-tracking-pixel/411698?noredirect=1#comment868892_411662) the tracking pixel will be) scrolls into view when I'm looking at another answer entirely. Example (this is not a posed picture, it happened organically as I was proofreading my answer and I thought "hey, wait a minute"):

  [image]

  I'm not "viewing" the answer at the bottom.

But a tracking pixel will claim I "viewed" those things.

I'd be very worried about any decisions made on the basis of this tracking pixel, given how wildly inaccurate it will be. Anticipating the "Oh, we'll be careful using this information" reply: Then why collect it at all? Humans like to see patterns in things. You'll see patterns in the data that you think you need to act on, which aren't really patterns that require action.

If you really want this information, I suggest investing in a more accurate means of collecting it, to avoid collecting duff data leading to duff decisions.

Comment: I've suggested debouncing the function for a several seconds to ensure the user is at least looking at the answer and not just scrolling past in the comments, but the reply is "maybe later"...

Comment: This is one of the parts that I tried to touch in [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411680/792066), since it seems like trying to validate an action that is set on stone, rather than observe and ask questions.

Comment: I've posted a detailed response in [my answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411724/3023052)

Comment: Your two sub bullet points make one wonder why you don't just sort by those available options when you are looking for things that way. Would probably save you a lot of time.

Comment: @TylerH - Frankly, "you're doing it wrong" isn't helpful here. The point isn't whether people should do it (I prefer handling exceptions to my normal mode this way, rather than changing the mode), but that *they do* do it, and it affects the tracking pixel. That's what's relevant here.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Good thing I didn't offer that response, then! I could have, but I presumed you had reasons, and was hoping to see them enumerated so that I and perhaps the devs could benefit from the perspective. Maybe I should have just offered that response, considering you were dismissive anyway.

Comment: That aside, different sort or scroll behavior is actually *not* that relevant to beginning to collect this data, since they know there are a whole host of things that will make the data not 100% accurate/meaningful. They were super clear about overcollecting in the comments (which, understandably, not everyone reads), but that info is edited into the post above now for everyone's benefit. Starting with a wide net, and then reeling it in, is a very effective strategy for gathering analytic data where you have none.

Comment: If SO wants to know what I am _reading_, then shouldn't they blur/obscure all content that I am not "focused" on?  I mean, if I want to unblur a particular portion of content, then I can just mouseover it on nonmobile (or tap it on mobile).  This would give SO _real_ clarity while compromising the UX! ...just saying.  For the record, I study incorrect/suboptimal/bad answers longer than I study correct answers that I actually use for work -- because I am an enthusiastic content curator. Maybe these pixels can be used to id voting abuse too -- when users read my answer for 1s before downvoting.

Comment: Is it possible to bracket answers with a pair of tracking pixels so you can track which ones are actually visible and for how long? That information could be used to infer which answers were actually being read, based on the event timestamps.

Comment: @mickmackusa - That's a good point about spending longer trying to figure out bad answers...

Comment: Is this feature the change that has recently rendered Stack Overflow unusable on all my browsers? The cursor disappears so I can't see what I'm selecting or where I'm about to click to type. Normal text has become unselectable and uncopyable. It's a train wreck.

Comment: @matt - I doubt it, that sounds more like the recent changes discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive). But FWIW, I haven't had issues like that or heard people discussing them re those changes. I use SO a lot, mostly on Chrome but sometimes on Firefox, and haven't had issues. If you have any Stack Apps installed, you might want to make sure they're fully up-to-date. I hope you figure it out!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder They seem to have fixed it during the downtime last night. Now we'll never know! :)

Answer (score 22):

Seeing that you announced this here at MSO, rather than MSE, am I right in assuming this is going to be implemented **only** on Stack Overflow, and not on the broader network?

Comment: Correct - if that changes we'll make a broader announcement.

Answer (score 14):

What do you learn from the data gathered? If an answer is very seldomly viewed, is this then a sign, that this answer needs to be sorted up, because obviously people are not finding it? Or is it a sign that the question is supposed to stay where it is, because people have found the answer they are looking for before? Simply the fact whether an answer has been displayed on some screen does not seem to indicate anything useful for that particular answer.

Let's say someone answers a question and the answer is generally valid and fine, so that it receives a number of upvotes. If a while later another answer is added, which is more detailed, better formatted, cites better sources, uses a clearer and more concise language and is more up to date, then there is the danger that this answer is never viewed, because it starts with zero upvotes and people won't see it. This is something I think you want to solve with "giving more weight to recent votes" to give those answers a chance. Good idea. But what do the views have to do what that. You say you want "to do data analysis for a new sorting algorithm that will weight more recent upvotes more heavily than older ones" But how is the views actually helping here?

I think you need to put the views into relation with something else.

So one thing I can think of that might actually help is the ratio between votes and views. A high votes/views ratio might indicate that the answer is worth sorting up.

On the other hand I have some doubts that this works out. Let's assume the top most answer is very specific and has high quality. Another answer has also high quality, but is slightly off-topic. Now for a very small portion of people the "off-topic"-answer is more valid. That is the type of people that will continue to scroll down and up-vote that answer. This will give that answer a high votes/view ratio. Does that indicate that this answer is supposed to be sorted up? I don't think so.

There is also the question on how the feature maybe mislead. Will the statistic be anonymous? Or is the user recorded? In case of the later: Are the views removed if a user is removed just like it happens with votes? What is with anonymous users in this case? Will views from users that are not logged in simply not count? If anonymous stats will count, this might mean that it is easy to intentionally mislead the system by generating certain patterns of "views".

What might be a better way of gathering data? Maybe a voting system? Oh it is already there...

I fear that if this data is there then it will be forcefully interpreted "somehow", no matter whether it makes any sense.

Maybe the whole idea is better thought out than what you present here. If so I suggest that you add more information on how you intend to interpret such answers. If not I suggest to first make a better plan.

Answer (score 6):

Are there any plans to use this in the “reached” metric?

As far as I know, the amount of people reached is calculated based on the metrics mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534/560258), and that bases it off of the view a question has (as long as the answer meets a couple other criteria), but now that views per answer are counted, are there any plans to use this to calculate people reached?

Comment: Currently there are assumptions made about answer views when calculating the "reached" metric. We are hoping that getting real data about answer views will allow us to apply more accurate calculations to the "reached" metric. However, no time frame on this.

Comment: @YaakovEllis - A tracking pixel near the voting buttons will not provide "real data."

Comment: If I post a long answer and the snippet is at the end (after a lengthy explanation), then the user's viewport will be below where the voting buttons are.  This will potentially draw the next answer's buttons into the viewport.  Seems really unreliable to me.  I find myself really agreeing with TJ.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder given that we didn't even have timestamped view information for the question page itself (for comparison with an answer creation date) this is at least a step forward. Plus, I suspect this particular method could be expanded to capture a little more information about how much of the answer was onscreen and for how long (without getting too chatty). I do wish more of that development would be done up front so it doesn't get stuck in this state. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @canon - I don't see collecting fundamentally-flawed information as a step forward, but I think I've made my views on it fairly clear. :-)

Comment: Yes, well... having flawed/incomplete data didn't stop them from building an entire metric on it. So, here we are. :P

Comment: @canon - What metric? Question views? Going to the question page is quite different to scrolling vaguely near an answer. I think I must be missing what you're referring to.

Comment: People reached, baby. lol

Comment: @canon - Oh, **that**. No one with any sense takes that metric seriously.

Comment: Precisely. But the only people who would even know better were involved in the meta discussion.

Answer (score 4):

My only doubt about tracking answer views is that a user must view an answer to determine the quality of that answer, *whether it is good or bad*. This means that the number of views an answer get wouldn't be directly determined by the relative quality of **that** answer, but by the absolute quality of **other** answers. Again, there's *no way for the user to compare the quality of two answers without viewing both of them*.

Suppose that the average user scrolls down through the answers until they find one that is "good enough". Then, if any answer exists that is "good enough", it should naturally result in a decrease in views in **any answers that appear lower on the page**, regardless of relative quality (since the user doesn't feel the need to keep scrolling after their problem is solved).

Comment: I always [doubt](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doubt#Verb) [the meaning of "doubt"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429), especially on Stack Exchange. Which one?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen I meant uncertainty about the efficacy of the proposed method. Feel free to edit the answer if there is any issue.

Answer (score -2):

You stated what you are going to do, adding answer tracking pixel, but you didn't fully explain why.

What is your end goal? What kind of metrics you expect to get, why you think it is important, and what will you do with the results?

The reason I am asking is that you seem to try to get some tangible metrics from answers that will help you assess how valid some answer is. But there is none. You cannot automate it. Only valid metrics are upvotes and downvotes and they can have flaws, too.

When I visit some page looking for answers, I usually read all of them, especially if all are on the same page. When I am moderating questions, again I read all answers (maybe not to the last letter).

The only exception are questions where answers span multiple pages. I usually switch to Active view on such questions, to make sure I see most recent answers, just in case. But again, just seeing the newest answer does not mean it is a good answer or a bad one.

And even now, I don't always vote on everything, good or bad.

If you want to combine views with voting patterns, you will not get better results either. I used Stack Overflow for years before I opened an account, and I had similar use pattern, the difference is that I couldn't vote. So if I found answer on the bottom and it was a better one you would not get any feedback from me back then.

Adding copying metrics is also flawed. Copying itself does not mean answer works, not copying also does not mean it does not work. Maybe you didn't need to copy because it was short code. Maybe it was just about a concept. Maybe you didn't need to copy because you already had your own solution, but only few lines of code were missing.

Can you please focus on more constructive ways of dealing with content, like how to add versioning, how to add warnings to dangerous content, how to review those. Who should be able to flag and judge the flags. Those are the things that can improve content quality.

I know that you want to measure before you act, but not everything can be measured. If it could, you would not need human moderators.

Comment: _"As part of the [Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project). <...>"_ The "why" is covered...

Comment: "*Copying itself does not mean answer works*" I'd often copy part of an post to put in a comment. And when I copy code on main, it's mostly to say there is some sort of problem with the code there.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, I understand that this is the part of "Outdated answers project" and even sorting algorithm is mentioned, but that is too vague.

Comment: You don't think it can be useful to determine how often a answer is viewed, in regards to cleaning up outdated answers? They're not trying to measure answer _validity_, they're measuring answer's _usefulness_.

Comment: More precisely, they are trying to measure how many answers are viewed when comparing different sorts: If a person comes back again and again and views more and more answers, that means that the first shown answers aren't good. This will allow them to add another metric when creating a new sort.

Comment: @MegaIng "This will allow them to add another metric when creating a new sort" That is the thing. There are no better sorts. Only score counts, because people explicitly cast votes. The only other relevant sort would be sorting by versions. But there is no versioning support yet.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar You did not follow the Outdated Answers project, did you?

Comment: Both versioning supports is planned (for which a new metric for testing would make sense), and a new sort is planned that somehow values recent votes more than old votes, because active is not really a good way to find answers.

Comment: @MegaIng Oh, yes I did... and it is going in "the waste time on nothing useful direction"

Comment: Neither views nor copying is ever going to affect the sorting. Only votes and age of those votes is planned to affect sorting (AFAIK). But to test if this works, SO needs metrics (other than votes). Copying is one way, Views on answers is another.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: That's your opinion, and you're free to think so. Please remain constructive, though. For example, that last paragraph in this answer is just a jab at SE, it's unconstructive.

Comment: @Cerbrus I think it is pretty constructive. If you are doing things that are bound to fail, it saves you plenty of time, money and effort if someone says you are doing it wrong. What happened with "Flagging outdated answers" - nothing could be determined from the data, and I saw that from the first second.

Comment: _"things that are bound to fail"_ Again, that is your opinion, based on publicly available information.

Comment: @MegaIng If the views are not going to affect sorting, then how is views metrics useful? It may become useful after gathering data for a few years, then changing sorting, then gathering data for next few years.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Running A/B tests. You can see how people behave with one sorting and how they behave with the other sorting.

Comment: @MegaIng On anything that doesn't have huge amount of views such statistics will be skewed. I am afraid that determining the good sorting algorithm for the whole site will be impossible. On the other hand low traffic tags tend to have way less answers, so they might not suffer. This is why I asked about more details about what will be done with such data.

Comment: I think this answer will be better if you remove everything but the first two paragraphs. The rest is just you telling them that the data isn't going to be useless, which you don't know. That's just your assumption / opinion.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, I am perfectly aware that what I wrote is my opinion. Since it is mentioned that tracking is related to "Outdated answers project" I added some specific points arguing why view metric is mostly irrelevant to that. I would like to hear contra arguments to those specific points or possible some I haven't thought of.

Comment: You're assuming everyone uses SO just like you use it, you're saying the data is useless based on _your_ use of SO, and then you conclude the answer by saying it's unconstructive to track this information. As I said before, _all_ of these "arguments" can be countered by _"That's just your assumption / opinion."_ Nothing you stated in this answer is based on facts other than _your_ specific usage of the site.

Comment: @Cerbrus Since when it is required that meta answer must only contain facts? I am asking them to prove me wrong. To give me some convincing arguments that will make me reconsider my POV. I know they don't have numbers, but they do have some idea why they think views are important.

Comment: There's a difference between saying _"you're doing it wrong"_, and asking _"Why are you doing it this way?"_

Comment: I am OK with the content and format of this answer. It's criticizing the idea of relying on raw metrics for exploratory purposes. Which is kind of like saying, "stop trying to make a better curator robot and empower your human volunteers instead". I'm inclined to agree. I also got the feeling that SE might be just going on a fishing expedition for data that "sounds vaguely useful at first glace", ignoring the fact that it's got a community of expert coder curators that can classify a post as useful better than any algorithm ever could.

Comment: @Cerbrus Is that such a bad thing? You are telling me that I am doing it wrong and I am not going to hold that against you ;)

Comment: I'm not answering an announcement. I'm explaining why I think this isn't a good answer. Remind me not to explain my downvotes any more.

Comment: @Cerbrus I appreciate your comments. I tried to explain why I don't agree with them and your proposal to change the answer. I have though about it and decided I will stick to the original answer. I don't mind you downvoting because you disagree. That is what Meta voting is all about.

Comment: I guess they want to have answer view counts as additional metric besides votes to go into the trending sort order (the same way they were interested in copy actions for answers). And I like this answer, I think it points exactly at the crucial point. Answer view tracking doesn't seem necessary for a trending sort based on recent votes. This tracking hints that they may want to implement it differently.

Comment: Or maybe they should need it as a success metric for changing the sort order of the answers. Then it would have already been needed for the unpinning experiment.

Comment: @Trilarion I can make a success metric, how many times a question is seen. That doesn't mean is a good metric.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar "There are no better sorts." The word "better" here seems to be your injection. Megalng said "*different* sorts". Each sort is better than the others for *different things*. We can only currently sort by 3 things, but there are tons of other things we *could* sort by if only the options were presented/the features were supported. Length, LoC, number of revisions, version-tagged are just a few that I might find useful from time to time depending on the question being asked.

Comment: @TylerH I wasn't precise enough... I wanted to say that there are no better sorts when it comes to finding "the best answer" (the best is also a bit relative) on the page - answer score is most commonly the best one. All other sorts we have, have their place, I can also imagine sort by version + score, to make it easier to find answers for appropriate version on Q with many answers covering range of versions. Of course, there could be more sorts, but adding more sorts may be overkill at the end - especially if it is hard to determine how particular sort works.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I would agree with you on that; however, this effort isn't about finding the best answer, it's about measuring engagement with *all* answers so they can learn more about *outdated answers* and figure out ways to deal with them.

Comment: @TylerH I am still trying to figure out how visibility metrics will help with that. I am not against collecting this metrics - I am more worried about possible interpretations. I guess I will just have to be patient and wait some more to get answer to that.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I would consider it a "general research" thing rather than an "applied research" thing. They don't have *any* data on how often answers are shown/read right now. So they are starting with this to see what data they can collect (knowing they are over-collecting) and will, presumably, tighten things down over time to see how that data changes, and if they can then draw any meaningful inferences from it.

Answer (score -13):

I'm worried about something else... it seems that you already have the algorithm and will only track this as a way to tweak it. I hope is not the case for a simple reason:

- There's no way to order content that someone wouldn't be happy. [(*née* Reddit issue with ordering comments)](https://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html).

We already tweaked the system to show the top-voted answer first. Let’s see how it goes before we try to modify the ordering further. Maybe the problem is already fixed. AFAIK, there hasn't been any complain about the top-voted answer, just a general fear that it is not up-to-date ([which has better and scalable solutions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/213575)).

Comment: People have consistently complained about top voted answers being outdated and wrong, nearly as much as they've complained about accepted answers. While this may be more likely to be the case on very high scoring posts, so a small subset of questions - they may also be some of the most highly-referenced questions at the same time.

Comment: @Catija [citation needed] I've only seen arguments that the pinned answer to the top is outdated or wrong. And even the examples in meta literature show this. [The one that asks for the introduction of an obsolete vote is accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/441429), [this one about unpinning if the answer is negative scored is also accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264045), and well, going through the [list here repeats the same story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405302): _pinning the accepted answer was the problem_.

Comment: Note that in the case of the obsolete answer, it was also fixed by editing.

Comment: @Catija still waiting for the source of your claims. I provided mine :)

Comment: Here's an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411368/14991864) by [mickmackusa](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2943403/mickmackusa) on the post announcing the unpinning of the accepted answer, it brings up the problem new answers face when there are lots of upvoted old answers. With it having +101/-10 votes currently I would say people do consider this a problem.

Comment: We don't already have a sorting algorithm in mind. The need for data surrounding answer views have come up a few different times throughout the outdated answers project, this is just the one that pushed us into developing it.

Comment: I'm not as well versed in what meta posts exist out there, but [this article posted to Reddit last week](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/pp269o/if_you_copied_any_of_these_popular_stackoverflow/) provides recent examples where the highest voted answers were not the best answers

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat and yet, all the posts I linked outscore it. [+600](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326095), [+110](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264045), [+295](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261817). It seems to me that mick issue is basically something more of a confirmation bias of a potential issue.

Comment: @KylePollard Actually (yes, I know), the [source article shows how unpinning helped](https://littlemaninmyhead.wordpress.com/2021/09/15/if-you-copied-any-of-these-popular-stackoverflow-encryption-code-snippets-then-you-did-it-wrong/) since the ones that outscore every other answer is because it was also accepted. So, yeah, problem solved, those answers will not appear first so the complain of the post "popular StackOverflow encryption code snippets" are not that popular anymore. There were a flurry of downvotes on some of those answers and upvotes on competing answers.

Comment: @Braiam how does those posts having higher score mean that people don't consider oudated and highly upvoted answers being at the top a problem? Also you really underestimate the effect of time there, those posts you link are 5 / 6 years old while the one I linked there is barely a month old. Does that mean one should wait 5-6 years before deciding that there is a problem and it needs to be fixed?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat you can see the timeline of votes on those posts ;). Most votes (and by that I mean 90%) came the first two weeks of the posts. None of the posts where featured, like the one you linked.